format number in tikz plot
The following is an attempt to label an edge with the distance between two coordinates. If I exclude \pgfmathprintnumber from the node text, then I get a value of "120.57292pt", where as I want "120.5". I tried using \pgfmathprintnumber to format it, but I get the error
figures/01-triangles.tex|12 error| Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '120.57292pt' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near 'pt'..

My question is---how can I format the number calculated via veclen?
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) at (0, 0) {A};
    \node (B) at (3, 3) {B};
    \draw let
        \p{AB} = ($ (B) - (A) $),
        \n{AB} = {veclen(\x{AB},\y{AB})}
    in (A) -- node[left] {\pgfmathprintnumber{\n{AB}}} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


veclen returns a dimension with unity whereas pgfmathprintnumber requires a number without units. Just compute the number with pgfmathparse which returns the unitless number in pgfmathresult.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,
fixed,
fixed zerofill,
precision=1,}
    \coordinate[label=A] (A) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate[label=B] (B) at (3, 3);
    \draw let
        \p{AB} = ($ (B) - (A) $),
        \n{AB} = {veclen(\x{AB},\y{AB})}
    in (A) -- node[left]{\pgfmathparse{\n{AB}}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}
     (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


